# simple onmouseover to call javascript not working

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, onmouseover

In a simple html page I have:

```
<SCRIPT>
function Clicker(number){
if (number == 1) 
document.write ('<style type="text/css">body {background-color: #cccccc;}</style>');
}
</SCRIPT>
```

and in the html body:

```
<a onmouseclick="Clicker(1)" href="#">clic</a>
```

But when I click on the link nothing happens. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Why don't you just set the background of body with javascript, like style.backgroundColor= or apply a class that has a black background?

Comment: afaik it's onclick, not onmouseclick

Comment: If you do a `document.write` this way (after the document has completely loaded), it will replace the entire page contents with the thing you just wrote(the style element in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the style block probably won't effect a change in the background colour. To do that you have to manipulate the Document object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Clicker(number){
if (number == 1) 
    document.body.style.background='#cccccc';
}
</script>
```

Your click event should also be onclick:

```
<a onclick="Clicker(1)" href="#">clic</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change **onmouseclick** to **onclick**.

Answer (score 0):

You need 'onclick' like following.

```
<a onclick="Clicker(1)" href="#">clic</a>
```